# How can i format my images from filepath to the same way as mnist.load_data() in python?

Tags: python, image

How can I format my images from file path to the same way as `mnist.load_data()`?
I'm currently getting my images from a driectory/file path, how can I format these images the same way as `mnist` uses for `mnist.load_data()`?

Comment: which `mnist` package are you using exactly?

Comment: @YohanesGultom I imported mnist with "from keras.datasets import mnist" and loaded it thru X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = mnist.load_data()

Answer (score 1):

The `keras.datasets.mnist.load_data` actually just [loads a preprocessed pickle file](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/mnist.py). If you check the data type of `X_train` & `X_test` they are just a `numpy` 2D array of float representing images pixel value (0-255). While `y_train` & `y_test` are just `numpy` 1D array representing the classes/labels  (0-9).

So the first way to imitate that functionality is read you images using image processing library (eg. [opencv](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array & finally split them using [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = []
y = []

# convert color image to 2D array (grayscale) & rescale
data = cv2.imread('zero.jpg',0) / 255.0
label = 0 # label/class of the image
X.append(data)
y.append(label)

# loop trough all images ...

# split for training & testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
```

Another way that you can try is using keras [ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(color_mode='grayscale')](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). The output is an `ImageDataGenerator` object that can be passed to keras `model.fit_generator()` function. In order to make use this function, you should arrange your dataset into train & test directories where each of them contains subdirectories representing classes of the images inside them. Please find detailed explanation in [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).